# CloudFoundary (Pivotal Cloud Foundary) variables with scope space

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

I would like to define some environment variables for an space to manage multiple test setup within a single foundation.

Is it possible to achieve this and how can we do it?

The `srevg` and `ssevg` are to be run via **admins** and are foundation wide variables. I only need it for my space.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is no built-in concept of a org or space scope environment variable. You can apply them system wide, which requires admin access to the environment, or you can apply them for a specific app.

A couple things you can do:

- You can put [them in your application manifest file](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#env-block). Putting them in `manifest.yml` makes it less likely that you'd forget the value. You can also use [manifest variables](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#variable-substitution) if there are values you don't want to commit in your `manifest.yml`. Don't forget you can define multiple application's in one `manifest.yml` file, which means you can use [YAML anchors](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#minimize-duplication) to reduce duplication & share the same env block across multiple apps in the same `manifest.yml` file.
- You can use the [`do-all` cf cli plugin](https://github.com/ECSTeam/do-all) to run `cf set-env` across all apps in the same space (you can use it to run any command across the whole space). If you always use `cf do-all set-env` when you make changes, you should be able to keep the env variables in sync.
- You can use a user-provided service for the information you want to share instead. User provided services are shared by default across the space, so you can just bind the user-provided service to all apps in the space and they will all have access to the information (bonus: it's more flexible and you can bind to a subset of apps as well)